# How to make a reverse kick

Tags: sound-design, fl-studio, kick

I need to make a hardstyle kick, but i don't know what VST to use for Fl Studio. 
I've tried so many tricks but it doesn't get the sound that I want. 
If i have a C3 Bass with 0,5 sec. 
I should have another bass like C4 with 0,5 sec too and not less or more.

> I can't make a different lengths for each bass kick.

Sorry for my bad English. 
**Thank you.**

Comment: can you post a song with reference to the sound that you are after, reversing a kick sound is a standard procedure and not an aesthetic one , If you want a certain effect please post some sound/song describing it, otherwise just google reverse kick on FL studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correcly, you have a sample with an instrument sound, that you want to resample to a different (lower) pitch, while maintaining the playback speed and overall duration of the sample.

The operation you need is a frequency shift and you can find it (under that name or some variation of it) in most digital audio workstations or audio editing programs.

I'll take as an example the open source audio editor Audacity. Load the audio file of you sample into Audacity (assuming it' in a format recognizabe by the software, such as WAV or MP3), goto to the Effect menu, select Change Pitch, and set the parameters for your purpose.

[image]

As you can see, one of the options allows you to enter directly the current note and the desired note, as per your question (if I understood correctly).

If you're using a DAW, it should have a similar feature, look for Transpose, Frequency Transpose, Pitch Shift, Pitch Change, or some other variation of these names.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. But i need distort more.

Comment: Now, that's rather vague, "more distortion". Distortion can be achieved in many different ways and with quite different end results. Without more information my generic suggestion would be to search your DAW for an included distortion plug-in, or,  failing that, search the Web for a free VST effects plugin that features some kind of distortion effect (there are plenty ), but that's a shot in the dark without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes but, every hardstyle artist have the same kick...  I don't know how they get the same sound...

Comment: Máxima, I don't know what you mean by "hardstyle" and "kick" (is it kickdrum? ) . Perhaps if you can point to an example someone may be able to explain how to get the sound you're looking for.

Comment: When i say reverse kick I think about a distorted bass and duration of the whole sound kick.